# Can't add an object inside an object

Tags: javascript

I am looking some data to create a list of objects, i want to add some of the objects inside the parent object. Although the inner object gets created none of the properties get created with it...

This is what im trying to do:

```
for(var i in data){
    if(parseInt(data[i].prevr) == 0){
        nodes[data[i].id] = new Object();
        nodes[data[i].id].name = data[i].name;
        nodes[data[i].id].child = new Object();
    }else if(parseInt(data[i].prevr) > 0){  
        console.log('test');
        nodes[data[i].prevr].child[data[i].id] = new Object();
        nodes[data[i].prevr].child[data[i].id].name = data[i].name; 
    }
 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(nodes[5]));
```

The result shows this in console.log:

```
test
{"name":"Test2","child":{}}
```

Why won't it create the data for the child object?

My variable `data` holds:

```
[{"id":"3","name":"Test2","prevr":"0"}
{"id":"4","name":"Test3","prevr":"3"}]
```

Comment: What is the original `data`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills let me edit my question i'll add it in :)

Comment: Your code [works fine](http://jsbin.com/ajejav/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(var i in data){
    if ( !data.hasOwnProperty(i) ) continue;

    if ( parseInt(data[i].prevr, 10) == 0 ) {
        nodes[data[i].id] = { name: data[i].name, child : {} };
    }
    else if ( parseInt(data[i].prevr, 10) > 0 ) {  
        console.log('test');
        nodes[data[i].prevr].child[data[i].id] = { name: data[i].name };
    }
 }
console.log(JSON.stringify(nodes[5]));
```

Comment: What does `if ( !data.hasOwnProperty(i) ) continue;` do to solve the issue?

Comment: That's not all I changed...but you should use that when using a `for...in` loop with arrays, otherwise prototyped array methods are included in the object's properties as possible values `i`